# Custom computing function for dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

df0

```
     a  b 
  c  0  6
  d  0  9
```

df1

```
     a  b
  c  3  2
  d  0  0
```

I have a custom divide function:

```
def cdiv(x,y):
    if x == 0:
        return 0
    return x / y
```

Result I expect:

```
     a  b
  c  0  3
  d  0  Inf
```

How could I apply the function for those two dataframe?

Comment: Do you actually need a custom function? `(df0/df1).fillna(0)` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df1.div(df2).mask(df1 == 0, 0)
print (df)
     a         b
c  0.0  3.000000
d  0.0       inf
```

Or maybe can works as [ayhan commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43890744/custom-computing-function-for-dataframes-in-pandas/43890831#comment74815414_43890744) if no `NaN` values in `DataFrames`:

```
(df0/df1).fillna(0)
```

Another solution with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1 == 0, 0, df1 / df2), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
     a         b
c  0.0  3.000000
d  0.0       inf
```

Comment: what if it is a custom functio and not just a simple divide?

Comment: @user-2147482637 - Then use `apply` - [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: I see that, but it is iterating over a single dataframe column or row, how to make it iterate over two dataframes together?

Comment: @user-2147482637 - It is obviously problem, need concat both DataFrame to one and then use custom function. Maybe the best create new question, because without data and function not idea.

Comment: Okay I made a question here, thanks for any help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321613/how-to-apply-a-function-between-two-pandas-data-frames